# Criar uma treeview que aceite um observable array como entrada

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs

Olá,

Eu preciso criar uma treeview que aceite um observable como entrada para que a medida que eu remova/adicione um nó na árvore a mesma atualize. Andei pesquisando e muitas pessoas utilizam o template biding para fazer isso entretanto, ainda estou meio confuso com relação a sua utilização.

Abaixo segue a minha tentativa de código. Nela eu cnsigo imprimir apenas o primeiro elemento da árvore e não seus filhos.

```js
var ViewModel = function(){
 self = this;
 self.data = ko.observable(data);
    
  debugger;
}

var data = {
    items: [{
        "name": "MORPHED",
        "items": [{
            "name": "5 Day",
            "items": [{
                "CategoryId": 20,
                "name": "30 day countdown"
            }, {
                "CategoryId": 19,
                "name": "Staffing your program"
            }, {
                "CategoryId": 22,
                "name": "Emergency/Medical Information"
            }, {
                "CategoryId": 18,
                "name": "Promoting your program"
            }, {
                "CategoryId": 21,
                "name": "Week of camp"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "4 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "1/2 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "Age Targeted",
            "items": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "CREATE",
        "items": [{
            "name": "5 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "4 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "1/2 Day",
            "items": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "INNOVATE",
        "items": [{
            "name": "5 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "4 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "1/2 Day",
            "items": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "ENVISION",
        "items": [{
            "name": "5 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "4 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "1/2 Day",
            "items": []
        }]
    }]
};

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: $root.data().items }"></ul>

<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: $root.data().items }">
        </ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

[Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/luizvnasc/h6nhgc38/) segue o exemplo que estou me baseando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta pode ser dividida em duas. A primeira se refere a mostrar a árvore, com um template recursivo. A segunda se refere a realizar operações de edição/inclusão/exclusão de itens na árvore.

### 1. Recursividade

Para usar o template (sem as funções de adicionar ou remover) você primeiro, precisa saber para onde seus templates estão apontando:

O código abaixo não funciona porque você está apontando para `data()` como uma função, sendo que ele é apenas o nome da sua variável.

```
     <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: $root.data().items }"></ul>
```

Para o primeiro nível da árvore você precisa apenas apontar para as propriedades do modelo que você quer mostrar, nesse caso, `items`, assim :

```
     <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: $root.items }"></ul>
```

Ou assim (já que o primeiro nível já é `$root`):

```
     <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: items }"></ul>
```

Agora nos níveis abaixo, como você não está mais no `$root` é necessário referenciar o item atual com `$data.items` no `foreach`:

```
<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: $data.items }">
        </ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

Assim a sua recursividade já está feita.

Fiddle

```js
var data = {
    items: [{
        "name": "MORPHED",
        "items": [{
            "name": "5 Day",
            "items": [{
                "CategoryId": 20,
                "name": "30 day countdown"
            }, {
                "CategoryId": 19,
                "name": "Staffing your program"
            }, {
                "CategoryId": 22,
                "name": "Emergency/Medical Information"
            }, {
                "CategoryId": 18,
                "name": "Promoting your program"
            }, {
                "CategoryId": 21,
                "name": "Week of camp"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "4 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "1/2 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "Age Targeted",
            "items": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "CREATE",
        "items": [{
            "name": "5 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "4 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "1/2 Day",
            "items": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "INNOVATE",
        "items": [{
            "name": "5 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "4 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "1/2 Day",
            "items": []
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "ENVISION",
        "items": [{
            "name": "5 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "4 Day",
            "items": []
        }, {
            "name": "1/2 Day",
            "items": []
        }]
    }]
};
 
ko.applyBindings(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: items }"></ul>

<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: $data.items }">
        </ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

### 2. Operação nos itens

O segundo problema é um pouco mais complexo, visto que você precisa que o seu array seja observável como um todo. Um `observableArray` permite que itens adicionados ou removidos sejam automaticamente refletidos no seu array, dessa forma você precisa de um modelo que contenha essas operações. Para evitar verbosidade , postarei o mínimo para esse conjunto de operações:

Modelo funcionando com as operações necessárias: https://jsfiddle.net/claykaboom/m4vws8s2/

Modelo com dados pré-carregados através de recursão:
https://jsfiddle.net/claykaboom/vb80r7xr/

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu estava procurando fazer.